# Prove that a sequence is Cauchy using the definition

Tags: real-analysis

$\begin{cases}
U_{1} = 1
      \\
U_{n+1} = \sqrt{U_{n}²+\frac{1}{2^{^n}}}
   \end{cases}$

Given the following inequality prove that it's a Cauchy sequence:

$U_{n+1}\:\le \:U_n\:+\:\frac{1}{2^{^n}}$

I have proved before that it's an increasing sequence so we can do

$0\le \:\left|U_{n+1}\:-U_n\:\right|\le \:\frac{1}{2^{^n}}$

And now using Squeeze theorem I find that $\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left|U_{n+1}\:-U_n\:\right|\:=\:0$

Which means that it's a cauchy sequence.

But how do I go about proving this using the (ε, N)-definition of cauchy sequence?

Answer (score 1):

$U_{n+1}-U_n \to 0$ is not the same  as as $(U_n)$ being a Cauchy sequence. For example $U_n=1+\frac  1 2+\cdots+\frac 1n$ satisfies this condition but it is not Cauchy.

$$|U_{n+m}-U_n|$$ $$\leq |U_{n+m}-U_{n+m-1}|+|U_{n+m-1}-U_{n+m-2}|+\cdots+|U_{n+1}-U_n|$$ $$\leq \frac 1 {2^{n+m-1}}+\frac 1 {2^{n+m-2}}+\frac 1 {2^{n}}< \frac 1 {2^{n+m-2}}.$$ Hence,  there exists $n_0$ such that $|U_{n+m}-U_n|<\epsilon$ for all $m$, for all $n >n_0$. This proves that $(U_n)$ is Cauchy.

Comment: I don't understand how did did you get this inequality.